# H2: Error with a multi-row insert statement

Tags: java, sql, h2

I'm using an in-memory H2 database with an initialisation SQL script. The following table is created:

```
CREATE TABLE GINA_T_WAM_GUESTDOMAIN (
    WFD_C_NAME VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    WFD_C_BASEURI VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (WFD_C_NAME, WFD_C_BASEURI),
    FOREIGN KEY (WFD_C_NAME) REFERENCES GINA_T_WAM_GUEST(WFG_C_NAME)
);
```

Now I can insert some rows in that table like this:

```
INSERT INTO GINA_T_WAM_GUESTDOMAIN(WFD_C_NAME,WFD_C_BASEURI)
    VALUES('DEVINT', 'https://dev.etat-ge.ch');

INSERT INTO GINA_T_WAM_GUESTDOMAIN(WFD_C_NAME,WFD_C_BASEURI)
    VALUES('DEVINT', 'https://devtech.etat-ge.ch');
```

But when I try to insert both rows in a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO GINA_T_WAM_GUESTDOMAIN(WFD_C_NAME,WFD_C_BASEURI)
    VALUES('DEVINT', 'https://dev.etat-ge.ch'),
    VALUES('DEVINT', 'https://devtech.etat-ge.ch');
```

I get the following error message:

> Column count does not match

Does anyone knows about this issue? is it at all possible to insert several lines in one statement?

Comment: Have you tried: `VALUES('DEVINT', 'https://dev.etat-ge.ch'),('DEVINT', 'https://devtech.etat-ge.ch');`?

Comment: @user1170330 Just did: it works. Make that an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how you can insert multiple rows at the same time in a single SQL statement:

```
VALUES('DEVINT', 'https://dev.etat-ge.ch'),
      ('DEVINT', 'https://devtech.etat-ge.ch');
```

It's called **row value constructor** and is a standard since SQL-92.

---

Source: http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/shadow/sql/sql1992.txt (Chapter 7.1)